# Proof with Taylor Series and the derivative of the function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have this problem:

Let $P_{n}$ be the n-th Taylor polynomial of $f$ around $c$. Proof $P_{n}(c) = f(c)$ and $P_{n}^{(m)} = f^{m}(c)$ for $1≤m≤n$

I've tried to use the expansion of the Taylor series but I get nowhere. Then I used induction but I couldn't get to the inequality $1≤m≤n$. Is there another approach to the proof with or without the expansion of the series or by induction?

Answer (score 1):

By definition
$$ P_n=\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}(X-c)^k} $$
It follows directly that $P_n(c)=f(c)$. Moreover, if $m\in[\![1,n]\!]$, you have
$$ P_n^{(m)}=\sum_{k=m}^n{\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}k(k-1)\ldots(k-m+1)(X-c)^{k-m}}=\sum_{k=m}^n{\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{(k-m)!}(X-c)^{k-m}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}{\frac{f^{(k+m)}(c)}{k!}(X-c)^k} $$
By the same argument $P_n^{(m)}(c)=f^{(m)}(c)$.